# Power BI DAX conditional measure returns duplicates after selecting rows from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

this is my first question, so feel free to give feedback or ask for additional info :)

My problem concerns a measure in PBI DAX with the goal to:

1. return a blank value if 'Price' and 'Budget' in the corresponding row equal 0
2. return -1 if 'Budget' in the corresponding row equals 0
3. return 1 - [Measure Price] / [Measure Budget]

To achieve this, I wrote the following code:

```
[Revenue  [%]]] = 
VAR Price = [Measure Price]
VAR Budget = [Measure Budget]
RETURN
IF(Budget = 0 && Price = 0, "",
IF (Budget = 0, -1, 
1 - DIVIDE([Measure Price], [Measure Budget])))
```

The measures [Measure Budget] and [Measure Price] are simple sums of the regarding columns.

It works fine until I activate the measure and display columns from another table in the visual. As long as I display only the columns of table 1 and the measure or columns from table 1 and table 2 without the measure it seams to work. The tables are connected by a 1:* relationship with crossfilters direction set to both. The relationship refers from a unique ProductID in Table 1 to multiple ProductIDs in table 2.

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgoCr.png)

Thanks, Samuel!

Comment: Where's your sample data and expected result?

Comment: I updated my post and provided the expected result. How can I upload the sample data? stackoverflow denies my wetransfer link